# Using STL containers with a class containing its own key

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered

I have an ***object***, which can be ***identified by its name***, and I want to place it in one of the ***STL containers***.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    //getters and setters, other functions
private:
    std::string name;
    //other member variables
};
```

So at first I thought that the usage of ***map-like structures*** is irrelevant in my case, because in those structures the identifier (the key) is separated from the class itself. Using a map I must return the name variable and **copy it "outside"** the class (waste of memory and illogical, breaking OOP rules).

My next shot was the usage of ***set-like structures***. In this case I only have the key field, where I load my whole object. Using this method I must overload my <, > and == operators in order to use an object as key. I can even make a functor for hashing if I use unordered_set, it works just fine. The problem here is that **I cannot use the container functions** as I would with a map. This is valid `mapInstance.find("example")`, and this is not `setInstance.find("example")`. I must create an object with the member variable `name` set to "example" and pass it to the `find()` function. The problem with this solution is that the other member variables in my class are **duplicated and not used**. I even tried overloading the <, > and == operators for `std::string` and `MyClass` classes, which works fine if I use them like this `stringInstance < MyClassInstance`, but the container functions are unusable (I even tried to overload the functor to work with a string with no success).

Can you suggest me a simple way (or a way), how to solve this problem with `std::set` or `std::map`(maybe others)?
In `std::map` the key cannot be a reference (as I know), and I don't know how to resolve it with `std::set`.

***Note:*** The problem with storing a pointer in a `map`'s key field is that if we change our mind and use `unordered_map` instead of `map`, the hash will be calculated based on the pointer, not based on the string (the hash function can be overridden, but it seems very complicated for a simple task).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered `find_if` rather than `find`?

Comment: At least in C++14, you should be able to use [`find` without constructing a key](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: @Angew, I believe for that to work, you'd need to ensure that instead of the default `std::less` used, you provide `std::less<>` or something else with `is_transparent`.

Comment: Is the string identifier required to be dynamic and/or a string?

Comment: @Angew I think you just solved my problem! Can you show me an example how would one use it on std::set?

Comment: @CeruleanKnight I'm afraid not, I haven't looked into C++14 yet, so I don't know any of the workings/trappings.

Comment: @Angew Thanks anyway! I tried to look at some examples, but there are many reference sites, where this feature is not listed. I cannot find good examples either.

Comment: @Angew I wonder why that hasn't been part of the standard from the beginning? It's terribly useful. And CeruleanKnight, one of the interesting things about C++14 is that it's already implemented by the major compilers, so if it's not working for you try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: @MarkRansom C++14 it's "already implemented by the major compilers". I didn't know that, it's really great! I have the latest GCC compiler (I'm running Arch), but I think my compiler isn't set properly.

Comment: Here's the basis of my statement: [We have C++14!](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/we-have-cpp14) which only came out a week ago. Unfortunately they don't give any details about which compilers conform or what switches they might need.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think I managed my compiler flags, but I don't understand how to make this feature work. [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find). These templates only participate in overload resolution if the type Compare::is_transparent exists.

Comment: @CeruleanKnight Looks like a budding separate question. Try searching SO and Google and if you don't find anything, go ahead and ask it!

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself what your requirements for your container are.

Things to consider are:

- How many objects will usually be in the container
- What are the memory constraints
- How often will objects be searched for and which complexity is acceptable?

A std::map has some requirements which might conflict with your class. E.g. the key is not allowed to be changed once an element is added to the map. However, your class might change the name at every time. From this consideration it should become clear that a std::map cannot work with a reference to a string as the key.

In the simplest case, you might consider using a [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/) and [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) with a predicate to check for a special name. This would have O(n) complexity.

Comment: Yes, I know the name should be a constant. In my project it is implemented like a protected member and without setter function. The class's constructor sets the name variable. It is protected because child classes may change the string.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to build upon what's given to get the desired results.  I'd suggest that what you're looking for is a specialized adapter for your use case.

Here's a very basic implementation that you can build upon.  In many cases, the cache locality you get from using `std::vector` will give better performance than using a standard container that provides a similar feature set.

Given a simple type and some helper operators:

```
struct Obj
{
   int key;
   std::string name;
};

bool operator<(const Obj& lhs, const Obj& rhs)
{
   return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}

bool operator==(const Obj& lhs, int rhs)
{
   return lhs.key == rhs;
}

bool operator<(const Obj& lhs, int rhs)
{
   return lhs.key < rhs;
}
```

We can devise a simple `flat_map` class that provides the *basic* complexity guarantees of a map, but will meet your requirement of finding objects by key without constructing a value type (like you need to with a set).  Insertion gives more complexity, but lookups are of similar complexity.  If lookups occur much more frequently then insertions (which is the case most of the time) this can work well.

```
class flat_map
{
public:
   using container_type = std::vector<Obj>;

   // insert object into the set
   // complexity varies based on length of container
   void insert(Obj&& obj)
   {
      container_.emplace_back(std::move(obj));
      std::sort(container_.begin(), container_.end());
   }

   // find with O(log N) complexity    
   container_type::iterator find(int key)
   {
      auto it = std::lower_bound(container_.begin(), container_.end(), key);

      if(it != container_.end() && *it == key)
         return it;

      return container_.end();
   }

private:
   container_type container_;
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
   flat_map obj;

   obj.insert({1, "one"});
   obj.insert({2, "two"});
   obj.insert({3, "three"});

   auto it = obj.find(2);

   std::cout << it->key << ' ' << it->name << '\n';
}
```

You can extend the `flat_map` adapter in any way you see fit.  Adding the required overloads to meet your requirements, templatizing the parameters (allocator, comparisons, storage types, etc.).

Comment: In my case I should definitely use std::map, std::set, std::unordered_map or std::unordered_set, because I need fast lookup times. It's not a bad idea to make a wrapper, but I must somehow use the container's internal find function, because it is written specifically for the underlying data structure.

Comment: I can use a map, but there is this "duplicated key" problem. If I can work around this problem, I'm done.

Comment: If I use a set, I must somehow make searching possible, without creating a new object with the name "example", then pass it to the find function.

Comment: @CeruleanKnight Is duplicating the key really a problem? Are you memory constrained? Or is it just that you don't like the idea because it seems unnecessary redundant? You could manage a set/list of key strings and use (smart) pointers to it or reference wrappers, but I personally wouldn't want to pay the price of added complexity if not really needed. And it still holds that a map won't play nice if you change the key afterwards.

Comment: @oxygene I'm not really memory constrained, but the duplication process seems to be a bit forced. There must be a better way to solve this simple problem.

Comment: This `flat_map` gives the same lookup complexity as `std::set` and `std::map`, and depending on your specific use case may actually be faster due to better cache locality provided by `std::vector`.  It's obviously not as good as the "unordered" versions, but you could also take the same approach and apply it to a hash table.

Comment: Beg your pardon but sort applied on a vector cannot be O(log n) even when inserting one element at a time. It will at least be O(n) on average. It can be O(log n) in terms of comparisons (like when you use lower_bound) but when you insert a new element it will have to shift the existing elements to make place for the new one. On average for random keys you will have to make (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1 + n)/n = (n+1)/2 = O(n) moves. By the way you can reach O(log n) for both operations using make_heap and all the something_heap family of functions.

Comment: Yeah, brain fart.  Insertion complexity is compromised, but lookup complexity remains consistent with `std::map` and the better cache locality of `std::vector` may give performance _gains_ in specific use cases.

Comment: @Chad I totally understand that one can build a library using std::vector to solve this problem. But the problem seems to be very simple and there must be a way to solve it with std::map or std::set. I thought that there is a straightforward way of doing it without "workarounds".